# Orthogonal family of curves to the level sets of $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} x_j$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, orthogonality

I read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897441/orthogonal-family-of-curves-to-the-level-lines-of-fx-y-xy-1) and realized that if I can solve the related problem below that it might lead to an application. Their solution led to a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Equation), so I suspect that my problem might lead to an [$n$-dimensional hyperboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid#In_more_than_three_dimensions) or something similar. But I am unsure how to proceed from defining the level set and the derivative. Perhaps I need to consider all pairs of products of reciprocal derivatives $\frac{dx_i}{dx_j}\frac{dx_j}{dx_i} = -1$?

For the function $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = \prod_{j=1}^{n}  x_j$ we can choose a [level set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set):

$$\{(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \prod_{j=1}^{n} x_j = K\phantom{space}\text{for some constant K} \}$$

The [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) with respect to variable $x_i$ is:

$$\frac{\partial f(x_1, \cdots, x_m)}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i} \prod_{j \neq k} x_j = 0$$

How do I complete the analsyis?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79003/proof-that-gradient-is-orthogonal-to-level-set

Comment: Do you want the *curves* orthogonal to all these level hypersurfaces? The best way to differentiate $f$ is to use logarithmic differentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the family of *curves* orthogonal to these level hypersurfaces. The reasoning you use with orthogonal lines in the plane will *not* suffice. The best way to see these is to find curves that, at any given point $p$, are tangent to the gradient of $f$ (vector of partial derivatives) at $p$, as this is the normal vector to the hypersurface. In your case, the easiest way to proceed is the following.

I will write $\log$ (but if you're used to $\ln$, it's that). Note that
$\log f(x) = \sum \log x_i$, so, by the chain rule,
$$\frac 1{f(x)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac1{x_i}, \quad\text{so}\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac{f(x)}{x_i}.$$
In particular, we want a curve whose tangent vector at each point $x$ is *parallel to* $f(x)\big(\frac1{x_1},\dots,\frac1{x_n}\big)$. Note how simple it is if we look for a curve
$$x(t)=\big(x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t)\big) \quad\text{with}\quad \frac{dx_i}{dt} = \frac1{x_i(t)} \quad\text{for all }t.$$
You can solve this by separating variables, as in basic calculus. You get
$$x_i(t)^2 = 2t + c_i, \quad i=1,\dots,n.$$
So, the orthogonal trajectories will be these quadratic curves
$$x(t)=\big(x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t)\big) = \big({\pm}\sqrt{2t+c_1},\dots,\pm\sqrt{2t+c_n}\big)$$
for various values of $c_1,\dots,c_n$.

Comment: I think each $x_i(t)^2 = 2t+c_i$ would admit to two solutions for $x_i(t)$, leading to $2^n$ possible choices of positive/negative sign to work out.

Comment: Oops. Yes, I forgot to type in the plus/minus. This is absolutely correct, as you can see in 2 and 3 dimensions.